# Custom Collection Form Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I have this formType

> ```
> class ParameterType extends AbstractType
> {
> public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
> {
>     $builder
>         ->add('vehicleType', 'choice', [
>             'required' => false,
>             'expanded' => true,
>             'choices' => [
>                 'turismo' => 'touring',
>                 'corsa' => 'ride'
>             ]
>         ])
>         ->add('historicalParameterDatas', 'collection', array(
>             'type' => new HistoricalParameterType(),
>             'allow_add' => true,
>             'allow_delete' => true,
>             'options' => array(
>                 'label' => false,
>             ),
>         ))
>         ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'save'));
> }
> ```

where, historicalParameterDatas as this Embedded Form

> ```
>  class HistoricalParameterType extends AbstractType
> {
>     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
> {
>     $builder
>         ->add('raceEdition', 'entity', array(
>             'class' => 'AppBundle:RaceEdition',
>             'choice_label' => 'year',
>             'label' => 'raceEdition',
>         ))
>         ->add('pilot', 'text', [
>             'attr' => [
>                 'maxlength' => 50,
>             ],
>         ])
>         ->add('copilot', 'text', [
>             'attr' => [
>                 'maxlength' => 50,
>             ],
>         ])
>         ->add('raceNumber', 'integer', [
>         ])
>         ->add('historicalAttachedFile', 'file', [
>             'required' => false
>         ]);
> }
> ```

So my form must be persist some information about one vehicle, about some raceEdition (that are saving in my db). What i need to do is let this possible, but some limitation. For one vehicle, an user can select one raceEdition only once. So, in the next historicalParameter (adding by symfony best practise shows about this case) the raceEditions selected in the previuos field will not selectable.

> ```
> <ul id='historical-parameter-list'
>             data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.historicalParameterDatas.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
>             {% for historicalParameterData in form.historicalParameterDatas %}
>                 {{ form_errors(historicalParameterData) }}
>                 <li class='form-inline'> {{ form_row(historicalParameterData) }} </li>
>             {% endfor %}
>         </ul>
>  function addNewExamForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
>         // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
>         var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
>         // get the new index
>         var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
>         // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
>         // instead be a number based on how many items we have
>         var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
>         // increase the index with one for the next item
>         $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
>         // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
>         var $newFormLi = $("<div class='form-group'></div>").append(newForm);
>         $newFormLi = $("<li class='form-inline'></li>").append($newFormLi);
>         $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
>         $("#pt_historicalParameterDatas_" + index + "_quantity").val(1);
>         addExamDeleteLink($newFormLi);
>     }
> ```

How can i do this? maybe with some javascript? I don't know how do.

Comment: Javascript for client-side stuff, [Doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) for persistence with a database of your choice

Comment: ok, i know this. I'm asking if exist a best practise symfony to resolve this usecase.

Comment: To my knowledge, check your values on the server side and return your template with optional error messages filled in and with settings. Which templating engine are you using? They should have options for loops, conditions and changing behavior based on input.

Comment: i'm using twig. obviously i can check this on server, but collection form in symfony work with javascript, is a way for embeed form. I presume exist something for make this control in frontend, before my server side control

Comment: So you want to persist something, which is server side, but do something with the result of that BEFORE it's sent to the server via the form post? How is your form supposed to know which db stored data you have already? At any rate, you could always just remove the option from the dropdown list if it has been used already. Rebuild the dropdown after a vehicle entry is completed, remove already linked options and you're done.